# Is it okay to use Thread.sleep as a timer in a console application?

Tags: java, timer, console-application, sleep

Had a quick question. In a Java application that I am writing, I want the terminal to print "Hello" but print 1 letter at a time but slowly.

Example:
H
(wait a couple seconds)
e
(wait a couple seconds)
l
(and so on)

What I'm doing is using Thread.sleep after each letter. So the question is that is it okay to use that method for what I'm trying to do? As in, is this an efficient use of a timer? If not, I'd love if you could please explain why and provide a solution.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("H");
    Thread.sleep(750);
    System.out.println("e");
    Thread.sleep(750);
    System.out.println("l");
    Thread.sleep(750);
    System.out.println("l");
    Thread.sleep(750);
    System.out.println("o");
}
```

I'm fairly new to using this forum, so I apologize if this question has already been answered. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Thread.Sleep() does not guarantee exact time elapsed:
it is only approximate "waiting" time

To better do a purpose like yours, you can use "Timer" class and the code will be better:

```
  public class TimerDemo {

   private int ptr = -1;
   String[] myStringArray = {"H","e","l","l","o"};
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      final Timer timer = new Timer();

      // creating timer task, timer
      TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             System.out.println(myStringArray[++ptr]); 
             if (ptr == 4) { timer.cancel(); }    
        }

    };          

      // scheduling the task at interval
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew,0, 1000);      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's something else your program should be doing between writing letters, then sleep is a perfectly adequate way of passing the time.